# update same row after update trigger

Tags: oracle

I have a little problem,i have to fields in the same table , ficha_terminada and fecha

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FECHA 
AFTER UPDATE OF FICHA_TERMINADA ON table_PRODUCT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     UPDATE table_PRODUCT SET new.FECHA = SYSDATE; 
END;
```

I just want to update the fecha field of the row when the ficha_terminada of that row is updated, is to now when is updated that line.

But is giving me an error in this line `UPDATE table_PRODUCT SET new.FECHA = SYSDATE;`

```
ORA-00904: invalid identifier
```

but the fields exists!!

Comment: What is your trigger's name?

Comment: Looks like your trigger NAME and column NAME are the same. Or am I seeing things?

Comment: is the same, but where is the problem with that, one is the trigger name and the other is a field of a table

Comment: Also shouldn't it be :NEW.FECHA ? Including the colon.

Comment: yes, but i supose that this trigger will upload all the lines of the table, how can i use where clause to identify the updated line id?

Comment: And what was the solution? I am curious!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is misuse of NEW reference: NEW. cannot be used in UPDATE as a target column for change.

You have to use PL/SQL in the trigger:

```
NEW.fetcha := sysdate;
```

Good luck

Comment: this give me the same error, i dont understand, i just want to update that fields of the line , when the other field of that same line is updated

Comment: Yep, I should add some more comments.Please, check RayCW's comment - it should be much clear after that. Thanks, Ray.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pavel's solution but in a before update row trigger.

Do

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FECHA 
before UPDATE OF FICHA_TERMINADA ON table_PRODUCT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     :new.FECHA = SYSDATE; 
END;
```